# How to replace NA to 1 in R?

Tags: r

I have tried other's R codes from this websites for similar questions, but none of them worked out, so I am confused. 
I am basically trying to replace all NA values in the 6th column called"Item4" in the dataset called "my_data1".
[image]

And those R codes that I have tried so far:

`b$a[is.na(b$a)] <- 1`
    `with(b, replace(a, is.na(a), 1))`

```
`df[,3:5][is.na(df[,3:5])] <-0`
df <- na_if(df, 'foo')
x[c("a", "b")][is.na(x[c("a", "b")])] <- 0
tidyr::replace_na(x, list(a=0, b=0))#
```

However, none of them work out in my dataset. those NA values simply do not be replaced by codes.

I will be really appreciated if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: please do not mark this question as duplicate or even close this question at the first glance. I do admit that there are duplicate questions on the website. However, as I said, I tried most of the R codes, and they are not helping. So I really need to get help from others.

Comment: What errors(if any) do you get?

Comment: Please show the output of `str(my_data1)`. Maybe these are not actual `NA` values but the string `"NA"`? Also, in your code you have different symbols for the data.frame: `b`, `df` and `x`. I hope you changed this to `my_data1` when you tried the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work: - replaces all rows in that column that equal NA.  If it doesn't knowing the class of your variables would help troubleshoot.  sapply( my_data1 , class )

```
my_data1[ is.na( my_data1$Item4) , "Item4" ] <- 1
```

Are the values appearing as NA in your screenshot, actually characters?  Try using dput to share the data - if so you will need:

```
my_data1[  my_data1$Item4 %in% "NA" , "Item4" ] <- 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. The second R code works. I did not realize the NA is the string instead of a number.

Comment: @JasminZhang - you may want to convert all the "NA"s to NAs, and than convert column 6.  You should check your classes here, I expect that your variable is a factor and not numeric - if you are taking means and such you will want to convert it.

Comment: @JasminZhang if this resolves the issue don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: Yep, this completely solved my problem. However, under which way can I accept the answer?

Comment: @JasminZhang - checkout this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers